# DLL in NuGet private server missing dependencies

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-spec

I have a .NET Framework 4.6.2 (hence non-SDK) DLL project which my company wants to move in a private NuGet server.

This project has some NuGet dependencies handled with PackageReference method and some 3rd party libraries currently stored in our repository and linked with plain old "Add Project References". I have compiled the nuspec as you can see below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package>
    <metadata>
        <id>Tools</id>
        <version>2021.09.03</version>
        <title>Tools</title>
        <authors>Premiata Ditta s.r.l.</authors>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <projectUrl>none</projectUrl>
        <description>My description.</description>
        <icon>Premiata.png</icon>
        <releaseNotes>
            &#9679; Rimossa la libreria da SuiteLibrary.
            &#9679; Compilazione automatica in .NET Framework 4.6.2.
            &#9679; Pubblicazione della libreria su NuGet.
        </releaseNotes>
        <copyright>Premiata Ditta s.r.l. 2021</copyright>
        <tags>Suite SuiteLibrary Tools</tags>
        <dependencies>
            <group targetFramework="net462">
                <dependency id="ServicesAPI.Model.DTO" version="1.0.5" />
            </group>
        </dependencies>
        <references>
            <group targetFramework="net462">
                <reference file="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
                <reference file="hasp_net_windows.dll" />
            </group>
        </references>
        <frameworkAssemblies>
            <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="Microsoft.CSharp" targetFramework="net462" />
            <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="PresentationCore" targetFramework="net462" />
            <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="PresentationFramework" targetFramework="net462" />
            <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System" targetFramework="net462" />
            <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Configuration" targetFramework="net462" />
            <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Core" targetFramework="net462" />
            <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Data" targetFramework="net462" />
            <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" targetFramework="net462" />
            <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Drawing" targetFramework="net462" />
            <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Management" targetFramework="net462" />
            <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Net.Http" targetFramework="net462" />
            <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Runtime.Serialization" targetFramework="net462" />
            <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.ServiceModel" targetFramework="net462" />
            <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Web" targetFramework="net462" />
            <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Web.Extensions" targetFramework="net462" />
            <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Windows.Forms" targetFramework="net462" />
            <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Xaml" targetFramework="net462" />
            <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Xml" targetFramework="net462" />
            <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Xml.Linq" targetFramework="net462" />
            <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="WindowsBase" targetFramework="net462" />
        </frameworkAssemblies>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="Premiata.png" target="" />
        <file src="C:/worksrc/DotNet/Librerie/Newtonsoft.Json/Newtonsoft.Json.dll" target="lib/net462" />
        <file src="C:/worksrc/DotNet/SuiteLibrary/BINARY46/hasp_net_windows.dll" target="lib/net462" />
    </files>
</package>
```

the upload comes with a warning (NU5128) but it works: in my test project I manage to see it and to download it with the dependency in the NuGet (ServicesAPI.Model.DTO), but there's no sign of the other assemblies.

What am I missing?

Comment: the "hence non-SDK" parens: doesn't follow; you can *absolutely* use SDK-style projects to build net462 tools - just use `<TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>`; this *might* be a simple way of improving the way the tooling responds here, and getting a viable nuget package?

Comment: why don't you move the 3rd party dependencies to package references?

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't get you, I'm quite new in NuGet world.

Comment: @DanielA.White Uhm, any link with examples? I've found this: https://newbedev.com/create-nuget-package-from-dlls

Comment: i would download the certain ones thru nuget itself - i wouldn't wrap existing ones